# Users are able to access old profile along with new one?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I have used Content Profile Module to make a content type of profile. I have then gone to my User management menu -> Permissions menu and given access to the "testuser" role to be able to create the new content type profile. Now when the user with the role logs on and clicks on "My profile" that has a path of sitename/user/username, he/she still goes back to the old profile and not the new content type I created. What am i doing wrong? All I want is users with "testuser" role to have a separate profile than the standard user. I sthis because my user has both roles of "standard user" and "testuser" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Drupal's access system is permissive: if any of a user's roles has a permission, the user will gain the permission as well.

It also sounds like you want to make the default tab for a user's profile to be your new content profile; if that's the case, check out this solution: [Drupal - Set 'user/%/edit/uprofile' to default tab on 'user/%/edit'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408602/drupal-set-user-edit-uprofile-to-default-tab-on-user-edit/3408969#3408969)

Comment: I looked at menu_alter and find it somewhat challenging (even though form alter is fairly easy). My custom profile content type is called custom_user_profile which I seem to be able to add into by going to /node/add/custom_user_profile. There is a link on a block on the right that says "My Profile" and has a path to "/user/username". Is there a simpler way to be able to go to node/custom_user_profile? I dont want the user with the custom role to be able to see /user/username as it takes him/her to old profile. I dont know if i am making sense.